# append php values with query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I just want to start by saying thanks for your help so far. I have successfully created an ajax request to display data in a dropbox but what is happening is creating a dropbox for each item in the database. where i want it create 1 dropbox with all items in it. and then have the ability to add another dropbox..

here is my new_order.php

```
<div class="page_forms">
    <div class="centered">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <div class="account-wall">
                    <div class="account-wall-title">
                        Select Products on Order
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="form-control btn btn-info">Add Product</a>
                    </div>
                        <form id="new_order_client_part_2" method="post" action="">

                        <div id="InputsWrapper">

                        <!-- This is where the dropbox will be displayed-->

                        <div style="clear:both"></div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="new_order_submit col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input class="form-control" name="new_order_part_2_submit" type="submit" value="Next">
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the product_request.php

```
<?php 
    include ("../core/init.php");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product`");
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

this is my main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID


var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e) {
    if(x <= MaxInputs) {
    FieldCount++;

    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'ajax/product_request.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
        {
            for (var i in rows)
            {
                var row = rows[i];          

                var product_id = row[0];
                var product_name = row[1];


                $("#InputsWrapper").append('<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="input-group"><span class="order_quantity input-group-btn"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Quantity"></span><select id="order_product" class="form-control" name="products[]"><option value="'+product_id+'">'+product_name+'</option></select><span class="input-group-btn removeclass"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">X</button></span></div></div><div style="clear:both"></div>');
                x++;
            } 
        } 
    });
}
return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
if( x > 1 ) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
    x--; //decrement textbox
}
return false;
}) 
});
```

So yeah i know the problem is in my append... it is appending the drop box for each result... I'm really stuck on how else i should write it...

thanks in advance if you can help :)

peter

Comment: Using javascript to append PHP code strings will not execute the PHP code. PHP is executed server-side before the page is served. I suggest using an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to fetch database data and generate HTML strings javascript can use to build the drop-downs.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, man I'm struggling with AJAX. Can you put me in the right direction in how I would write it?

Comment: Where are the other product lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to start by saying thanks for everyone help... i worked it out.

here is my new_order.php

```
<div class="page_forms">
    <div class="centered">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <div class="account-wall">
                    <div class="account-wall-title">
                        Select Products on Order
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="form-control btn btn-info">Add Product</a>
                    </div>
                        <form id="new_order_client_part_2" method="post" action="">

                        <div id="InputsWrapper">

                        <!-- This is where the dropbox will be displayed-->

                        <div style="clear:both"></div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="new_order_submit col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input class="form-control" name="new_order_part_2_submit" type="submit" value="Next">
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the product_request.php

```
<?php 
    include ("../core/init.php");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product`");
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

this is my main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var MaxInputs       = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
        var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID
        var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
        var FieldCount=0; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e) {

    if(x <= MaxInputs) {
        FieldCount++;
        $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'ajax/product_request.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
            {
                var product_id = rows[0];
                var product_name = rows[1];

                var options = $("#order_product_"+ FieldCount +"");

                $.each(rows, function() {
                    options.append($("<option />").val(this.product_id).text(this.product_name));
                });
            } 
        });
        $("#InputsWrapper").append('<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="input-group"><span class="order_quantity input-group-btn"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Quantity"></span><select id="order_product_'+ FieldCount +'" class="product_on_order form-control" name="products[]"></select><span class="input-group-btn removeclass"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">X</button></span></div></div><div style="clear:both"></div>');
        x++;
    }
    return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    if( x > 1 ) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
        x--; //decrement textbox
    };
    return false;
});


});
```

ALL FIXED AND WORKING CHEERS!!!

peter

Comment: @user3105700 how do you think i can re-write the above?

Comment: Are you making AJAX requests for a product list you already have?

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is not executed client side, so when you append the dropdown, the PHP is not being executed. A suggestion would be to use AJAX. I know I'm going to get a lot of crap about this down in the comments, but I feel jQuery's AJAX is the simplest to understand. You simply pass an associative array to the AJAX function. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "script.php", //File you wish to execute
    method: "GET", //Can be GET or POST
    data: "thing=1&thing2=2", //Just like the GET parameters in a URL
    success: function(data) {
        //Do what you want, data is the returned data from the PHP script
    },
});
```

For example, just taking a quick look at your code, for the "order_product" select you want to add, move the PHP to a different file, AJAX that, and append that as well. You could even put the append in the success function or make another AJAX call for more dependent selects.

Or, if you want to fetch all the data in one call and just add stuff dynamically(not sure if that is what you want, but it seems like it, maybe) you could use jQuery dependent selects. It isn't that difficult to write your own, but if your just looking for a drag-and-drop solution, here is the GitHub: [jquery-dependent-selects](https://github.com/simpleweb/jquery-dependent-selects). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `#AddMoreFileBox` in your HTML code. Are you missing something here ?
With your problem, I have 2 way to approach.

1. You can copy first div with class `col-xs-12` , then append into `#InputsWrapper`
2. With your sql result, you can assign it into javascript variable as
   Json in current php file. Then you can add new select with Json

var data = `<?php echo json_encode($sql_result);?>`;